# Is it possible to locate certain paragraph of a webpage without html anchor?

Tags: javascript, html

like if I want to locate the middle of this page,can I go there by adding something at the end of url before I knew if there's any anchor there?

Comment: You don't need anchors, any element id would work.

Comment: Yes with javascript you can do this. Yw

Answer (score 0):

`<a name="foo"></a>` (an "anchor") is a now obsolete method of jumping to a section of a webpage via the `#foo` fragment identifier section of a webpage.

HTML4, in 1998, introduced the `id=""` attribute which can be used with any element to allow it to be addressed via fragment identifiers, so `<p id="foo">` works just as well.

However, if an element does not have an `id=""` attribute value (which must be unique, too) then it cannot be referenced by a fragment identifier.

Your only other option is to use a "hashbang" address (that is `#!something`) where you'd have a JavaScript library parse `something` to select an element. This is a research task left-up to the reader. I suggest using the built-in `querySelector` or XPath functionality to address elements.

Comment: `name` attribute can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

URLs don't support searching through the document.

If you can modify the JavaScript on the page (that is you have access to the server or you can run client scripts with tools like [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/)), then you can attach a hash to the URL and get the value from JavaScript via `location.hash` and scroll.

If you can edit the HTML of the page, then you can add `id` attributes and scroll to them by appending them to the URL as a hash (i.e. `#foo` scrolls to the first element on the page which has the `id="foo"`).